# How to Dynamically Create and Populate Word Document Templates from Existing Word Files and HTML Forms? (Python, JS)

Tags: javascript, forms, openai-api, azure-form-recognizer, docxtemplater

### Preface

I’m working on a project where I need to digitize the form filling process for a testing lab company. The company currently fills out forms manually and makes 40 copies of each form. The form itself is obscenely large (138 pages, 300+ input fields). The forms are then given to a tester who jots down his observations. All of the results are combined back into a result form which is then digitized, printed, and sent to the government. It is imperative that the format is preserved.

The form name is [IEC 62368-1](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/85813) (I have attached an Image as I could not find a web downloadable version). There is a Data sheet and a Test Report by the lab, but all of this process needs to be digitized. I want to create a system where the forms can be filled out digitally, and the data from these forms is used to populate a Word document template. This Word document is then saved and can be printed or sent digitally.

Here’s an example of the data sheet:

#### **62368-1 Test Data Sheet**

[image: Image of Test Data Sheet]

And here’s an example of the corresponding report sheet:

[image: Test Report Sheet]

I want to create a system where a user can fill out a form (either an HTML form or a Microsoft Form), and the data from this form is used to populate a Word document template. The Word document should maintain the same formatting as the original document. The placeholders in the Word document should be added by the program.

### Additional Challeges and Preferences

1. The form needs to be in printable condition which raises the following issues:
2. Handling images when stitching back the document

   - these fields need to be resized in order to fit the image size on paper [image: Images]
3. Microsoft Stack is Preferred as the company deals in Microsoft Products. ( PowerApps, Azure OpenAI/ Document Intelligence)
4. The solution I have in mind is that I generate 2 templates each (Test Report and Data Sheet) which is filled by a form (Microsoft Form or a custom Form) and then using Microsoft Automate/Flows this data is sent into an azure function which aggregates all data sheet observations from multiple testers and does some processing and enters into the test report.
   The Test Report template would resize itself according to the input from the processed Azure Function (Image Fields would expand to the size and images can shrink to fit). Because of the template the layout would be preserved, and Azure functions can take care of the size fields. User will only need to upload Blank Data Sheets and Test Reports, which will be stored on their SharePoint with the processed files that I discussed above. The Manager would be notified when the processed files are available for download.

### What I've Tried

- I’ve tried using [docxtemplater](https://docxtemplater.com/docs/installation/) to create and populate the Word document, but I’m having trouble adding the placeholders to the Word document. I’m also not sure how to maintain the formatting of the original document.
- I have also tried Microsoft Forms into Word, but Forms has a character limit which this easily crosses (200 questions per form).
- I tried the Word Developer tab -> Microsoft Word Forms but then I would need to label 300 questions across 40 forms which is not at all possible
- The One thing that works almost perfectly is Adobe Forms and automatic labelling. It needs some input from the user, but it does most of it, which is the kind of result I am expecting but as its closed source I cannot resize Image input fields with custom JavaScript (which adobe can run)

Is there a way to do this using JavaScript or any AI service? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please upload and send a version of the docx file that have (in docx format). This way I could analyze how this form could be filled.

The problem I see is how would you bind the data to the correct field, some kind of mapping has to be done, either using {tags}, or some other method.

(I'm the Creator of docxtemplater)

Comment: @edi9999 sure, I can do that. I'll send a google drive link.

You created docxtemplater!! I'm honored. No wonder you understood the problem so easily (as compared to some other people)

Comment: @edi9999 

[Here](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AkfcMN6-DbPkslJqr6eHYYZaCHYF?e=L5O73T), Lemme know if there are any developements or you need me.

Comment: For some reason I can view this file in the browser, but the download option does not work correctly (only PDF download works, not docx). Could you upload the docx file instead and send me that ? Also, is the table called "Battery replacement test" also going to be filled in ? Do you want to fill in all comments or also all other cells ?

Comment: 1) `Could you upload the docx file instead and send me that ? `
I'll do that. 

2) `table called "Battery replacement test" also going to be filled in ?`
yes, all cells are to be filled.  **Some explanation** This is the raw data sheet 

all of its data is to be collected (with the help of distributed forms to testers) and compiled into a report sheet.

I am digitizing their documents for testing.

Comment: @edi9999 hey Sorry I am 2 months too late, but here is the [downloadable link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kfr8s4vVM5d9nIYr_jVlwmA_1FoCdkND/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103700131542521032287&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention python, you can achieve this with python using [docx-mailmerge](https://pypi.org/project/docx-mailmerge/)

```
from mailmerge import MailMerge   
document = MailMerge(your_doc_template_path)
document.merge(
   report_number = "xxx-xxx",
   date_of_issue = "2023/12/25"
)
document.write(destination_file_path)
```

but first, you need made a docx as your template and adding **MERGEFIELD** Mail Merge, Open your docx template.

```
(this MSWord for Mac, maybe slightly different with MSWord for Windows)
insert->field
on Category tab, choose Mail Merge and chose MergeField on Field Names.
```

Note: field name must be identical with the variable name that you assign of.
In my example, you need to add report_number and date_of_issue for the field name.

or you can follow the instructions from this link [Populating MS Word Templates with Python](https://pbpython.com/python-word-template.html)

Adding image can also be done using [python-docx](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/). combine docx-mailmerge and python-docx can be useful.

Comment: > but first, you need made a docx as your template and adding MERGEFIELD Mail Merge, Open your docx template.

@david but I cannot do that as the document is so big and is only one of 40 documents with 2000 fields.

:(